# how to open project with sub-projects in intellij for intellisense to work

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, intellisense

I have a main project with several modules/sub-projects in it. When I open it with intellij the intellisense does not work. The package naming also highlights in red. The sub-projects have gradle files but the main project does not. How do I configure it in INTELLIJ v2018.3?

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of days of trying to configure this type of setup I realized the following.  *First I was not able to use the Gradle View plugin in intellij. It works with gradle 3.5.0 and didn't allow some of my dependencies to compile if against the lower version of gradle ( < 4.0)*

1. I added 2 gradle files to the main project:

   settings.gradle

   > rootProject.name = 'volumes'
   >
   > include 'rest_api'

   build.gradle

   > apply plugin: 'idea'
   >
   > apply plugin: 'java'
2. In the terminal window, I am using the git bash command line; I run the following commands:

   > *gradle cleanIdea*
   >
   > *gradle idea*
3. I closed the IDE, re-opened it and saw a gradle link project pop-up. When I selected this option, I was able to check the box **Use auto import** and **Use default gradle wrapper** 
   Once I applied the changes (you may have to run a gradle build from the main project and it should import) now you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Add Gradle modules to an existing project using File | New | **Module from Existing Sources** and select build.gradle file to imort from. See [Importing a Gradle module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#import_gradle_module) for the steps.